# Responsive Menubar using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been created a responsive menubar which encountered a problem where when i click the dropdown button, there are no style at all.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("myMenubar");
  if (x.className === "menubar"){
    x.className += "responsive";
  }else{
    x.className = "menubar";
  }
}
```

```css
.menubar{
     position:absolute;
     width:600px;
     margin-left:35%;
     margin-top:4.5%;
    }
    
    .menubar ul{
     overflow:hidden;
    } 
    
    .menubar ul li{
     display:inline-block;
     margin-right:15%;
     list-style-type:none;
    }
    
    .menubar ul li a{
     text-decoration:none;
     color:white;
    }
    
    .menubar ul li.icon{display:none;}
    .menubar ul li a:hover{color:red;text-decoration:none;}
    .menubar ul li a.current{color:red;text-decoration:none;}
    
    @media screen and (max-width:765px){
     .menubar{
      width:130px;
      margin-left:57%;
     }
     .menubar ul li:not(:first-child) {display:none;}
     .menubar ul li.icon{
      float:right;
      display:inline-block;
     }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:765px){
     .menubar.responsive ul{position:relative;}
     .menubar.responsive ul li.icon{
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
      top:0;
     }
     .menubar.responsive ul li{
      float: none;
         display: inline;
     }
     .menubar.responsive ul li a{
      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      text-align:center;
     }
    }
```

```html
<div class="menubar" id="myMenubar">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

What i am doing wrong? I am using http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp tutorial and i change a bit of code to fit my design. I think the base are all the same

Comment: You can use Bootstrap framework for responsive

Comment: @SantoshKhalse okay,, i'll start my study,.. thank you for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change

```
x.className += "responsive";
```

to

```
x.className += " responsive";
```

At the moment, your class becomes `menubarresponsive` instead of `menubar` and `responsive`.

Answer (score 2):

Use it!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i will create a new one using your answer,, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OK...
So I will start by pointing out the mistakes:

1. There is an error in your css. `.menubar.responsive` selects all elements with BOTH of the class names *menubar* and *responsive*.
2. There is also an error in your javascript. The `classname` property is a string. Therefore `x.classname += responsive` will not add responsive as another class, but will concatenate the current classname with `responsive`, so the result will be `menubarresponsive`.
3. You did not assign `myFunction()` to any object.

**Solution**

You could either change your css, which I will not recommend as it is a lengthy processs, or alter your javascript code. Here I changed your logical if statement to a simple statement that toggles the `responsive` class.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('myMenubar').classList.toggle('responsive');
}
```

```css
.menubar{
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
    margin-left:35%;
    margin-top:4.5%;
}

.menubar ul{
    overflow:hidden;
} 

.menubar ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:15%;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menubar ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}

.menubar ul li.icon{display:none;}
.menubar ul li a:hover{color:red;text-decoration:none;}
.menubar ul li a.current{color:red;text-decoration:none;}

@media screen and (max-width:765px){
    .menubar{
        width:130px;
        margin-left:57%;
    }
    .menubar ul li:not(:first-child) {display:none;}
    .menubar ul li.icon{
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:765px){
    .menubar.responsive ul{position:relative;}
    .menubar.responsive ul li.icon{
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:0;
    }
    .menubar.responsive ul li{
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    .menubar.responsive ul li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar" id="myMenubar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="current" onclick="myFunction()">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```